# How to get max/min of a list in a Jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 to create template like this:

[image]

Here, I need to adjust the bar chart's height, making the longest column to 100% width. That is, in my jinja template

```
<div class="power" style="width:{{ star_4_percent }}"></div>
```

need to changes to

```
<div class="power" style="width:{{ star_4_percent/max([star_1, star_2, star_3, star4, star_5]) }}"></div>
```

However, Jinja seems not support the `max` function, as I see in its [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/). What should I do?

I find `max/min` implementation in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html, but this is not the official implementation.

Comment: you can `sort` the list and then pick `first` and `last`

Answer (score 10):

Use [Jinja2 Filters](http://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html). Your code will be:

```
<div class="power" style="width:{{ star_4_percent/([star_1, star_2, star_3, star4, star_5]|max) }}"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a list of calculated width value.

`{% set width_list = [star_4_percent/star_1, star_4_percent/star_2, star_4_percent/star_3, star_4_percent/star4, star_4_percent/star_5] %}`

Then apply the sort filter and select the last element in the list.

`<div class="power" style="width:{{ width_list[-1] | sort }}"></div>`

The sort filter sorts in ascending order so by selecting the last index, you will get the max value.

Comment: @volent saw your edit in the review queue, you're probably right with your modification, but I think Zenara Daley should take a look and approve it.

Comment: Ad @lrnzcig: Link to the suggested edit (for the case it gets rejected): https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17388556

Comment: I'm not a Jinja expert, but the original answer's syntax doesn't seem to work for me. The corrected version is right.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Zenara's answer, if you want to make it single line:

`<div class="power" style="width:{{ star_4_percent/(([star_1, star_2, star_3, star4, star_5]|sort)[-1]) }}"></div>`